remove normal map with image texture on all materials via python?
I want to delete all normal maps with the image texture noded to it.
I have this script which only deletes the normal map but keeps the image texture. What do I need to change?
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    if mat.node_tree:
        nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
        names = [n.name for n in nodes if n.type == 'NORMAL_MAP']
        for name in names:
            nodes.remove(nodes[name])


The node you're deleting is just accessing the image datablock. Those are found under the bpy.data.images category. It also seems like you're only finding and deleting the Normal map node, not the image texture node. So thats why it's not deleting it.

yes, delete the Image Texture node or remove the image from it. Follow the link from the slot and check if the connected node is an Image Texture node. If you delete the node and the image is not used elsewhere then it should become an orphan/unused data that will be discarded (=not saved) when the blend file is saved next time.
